# PDF field to query SQL database

Tags: sql-server, pdf

I'm attempting to find a way that a user can click a button (or something along those lines) on a PDF to query the SQL database.  I have the query running the way I want it to run.  My only problem is figuring out how to set up the connection from the PDF file to query the database.

This PDF is a template that the user will fill out completely except for one field.

Will this require an ODBC connection?  Any suggestions?

Comment: I am not super knowledgeable about this in a pdf document but it seems to completely go against the concept of being a portable document. Yes it would require a database connection but this kind of thing seems to be a better fit for something that isn't a pdf.

Comment: Your question is unanswerable. Nowhere in ISO-32000-1 (the PDF specification) will you find any reference to ODBC connections or getting data from a database to fill out a PDF form or update a PDF. Specific implementations may provide this functionality, but so far I only know one and it requires every user to have Adobe software (the free Adobe Reader isn't sufficient).